# Flutter - Getting Profile URL by using Linkedin API and linkedin_login Package

Tags: flutter, dart, linkedin-api, dart-pub

I am trying to create **Flutter** app that authenticates first either with **google** or **email** authentication and later Adds the **LinkedIn** profile.

Rather than allowing users just to type their profile URL is there a way to know if a user who has authenticated with the [linkedin_login](https://pub.dev/packages/linkedin_login) package from PUB.

I tried this package and it works but it only gets the email, first name, last name, profile picture, access token, and userID.

I need to get the profile URL of the person who authenticates with this. I tried the Linkedin API docs and it did not make much sense to me.

Anyone with experience in using this can help my cause. Explain The API calls and the setup for this as well.

PS: Explain like you're teaching a noob.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi  @adarsh-balu, for me it's not so clear what you actually want? In the whole of your text, there is no question mark? I'm owner of LinkedIn package that you have mentioned, and probably I can help you, or at least give you directions, but please give me a more clear question?

Comment: Do you need to have URL after you logged in with plugin?

Comment: @NihadDelic All I want is to get the profile information of the users who have authenticated using this plugin. This info includes education, about, experience, etc.

Comment: please check my edited answer. Probably you will not get better info from this. Please accept my answer if you think that this explanation can help you, or it is resolved your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me will return : firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id

r_emailaddress will return : emailAddress

for position and headline or for calling: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/profile-api - you have to apply for r_basicprofile to Linkedin because their information not available in V2 r_liteprofile

Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

To sum up: You need to have a LinkedIn partner program, and you will get this information, but it is very hard to be accepted [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply).

And the reason why is this so complicated no one knows except Linkedin guys https://thenextweb.com/dd/2015/02/12/linkedin-takes-aim-developers-plans-lock-apis/.